# Naming convention for IoC intended interfaces

Tags: c#, unit-testing, oop, mocking, inversion-of-control

When you use IoC frameworks you end up creating interfaces exclusively for the sake of IoC. I'm tempted to use a naming convention for those ones.

For example, without IoC on the picture, you may have the following business domain driven structure:

```
interface IBodyPart
{
    string ScientificName { get; set; }
    string StreetName { get; set; }
}

class Head : IBodyPart
{
    public string ScientificName { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
}

class BodyPartPoker
{
    bool isSituationAcademic;
    BodyPartPoker(bool isSituationAcademic)
    {
        this.isSituationAcademic = isSituationAcademic;
    }

    void Poke(IBodyPart bodyPart)
    {
        if (this.isSituationAcademic)            
            Debug.Print($"Proceeding to poke {bodyPart.ScientificName}");            
        else            
            Debug.Print($"Poking that {bodyPart.StreetName} LOL");
    }
}
```

Now let's say you want to use IoC to inject `BodyPartPoker` instances. You also want to use some kind of unit test mocking framework to test that logic.

In this case, even if you don't have a business-domain case for it, you will introduce the `IBodyPartPoker` interface:

```
interface IBodyPartPoker
{
    bool IsSituationAcademic { get; set; }
    void Poke(IBodyPart bodyPart);
}

class BodyPartPoker : IBodyPartPoker
{
```

My question is: would it make sense to have a naming convention for interfaces like `IBodyPartPoker` so we explicitly establish it's purpose to be not business-domain related?

Say ....

```
interface IIocBodyPartPoker
```

Comment: I'd say it would not make much sense to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, the convention is typically to leverage the language's idiomatic naming conventions, and name an interface with a preceding `I`, as in `IBodyPartPoker`. That leaves the `BodyPartPoker` free as a name for a class.

In Java, the convention is to name an interface without Hungarian notation, so the interface would typically be named `BodyPartPoker`, which then often causes people to name their single class something like `BodyPartPokerImp`.

You should consider this a code smell, exactly because it seem that the only reason the interface exists is to enable unit testing. You could say that it violates the [Reused Abstractions Principle](http://www.codemanship.co.uk/parlezuml/blog/?postid=934).

Giving the interface another name, like `IIocBodyPartPoker`, isn't going to solve the fundamental issue.

If an interface exists exclusively to support unit testing, you'll most likely find that the tests are too coupled to implementation details, and that every time you try to refactor your production code, tests break. Again, a naming convention will not address such issues.

Comment: I already had the impression of that being a code smell, however, I work in an environment where saying that could be very polemic. I'm rather new in that work environment so I try to play by the existing practices unless I have a very strong case.  My perception from the team and also from the online agreement is that *most* people don't mind creating an interface just for the sake of IoC. Now the challenge for me is to PoC a refactored version of my team's code that doesn't introduce interfaces just-because and at the same time works ... while being unit-test friendly. Thanks.

Comment: That is easier to understand code by breaking tests and seeing what exactly braked and why, instead of tying refactor unknown dead wall of code, even with good comments. Also you will never know how much you will need to refactor anyway, shat seems stable part today will be in trash can tomorrow. So i totally disagree with last statements of this answer, im sorry.